# TFS to GitHub and viceversa sync

Tags: git, github, tfs

I dont know whether this is possible, but would like to know if we can do this?

Our client is using GitHub, and we are using TFS.

We dont want to change any of our settings, and want to continue on the work. But would like to sync the projects from TFS to Github and from GItHub to TFS as batch process every 30 mins, or whenever the change is made.

Any help or any pointers for implementing the same would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: For your TFS source control are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: I am using TFS and GITHUB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no this kind official tool or services. You have to manually do the sync. Such as setting up two remotes in a local Git repository, i.e

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/foo/bar.git
git remote add origin https://tfsserver/DefaultCollection/_git/bar
```

> And then simply do a git pull upstream master followed by a git push
>   origin master assuming that master is the branch that you want to keep
>   in sync.
>
> With either version control system, you probably want to keep a branch
>   in version control in your TFS repository to match what is in your
>   upstream GitHub project so that you can easily see change coming in
>   the one place and then handle your merges inside your local
>   repository.
>
> *Source Link:
>   [Integrating Github code to TFS - auto check-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380169/integrating-github-code-to-tfs-auto-check-in)*

Another workaround is with help of a special build in TFS, then calling git command during the build pipeline. Detail steps please refer this blog: [Keep Git repository in sync between VSTS / TFS and Git](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/10/22/keep-git-repository-in-sync-between-vsts-tfs-and-git/) You could also use the [Git Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.gittasks) in marketplace.

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for the reply,  I was able to do most of the commands using git tfs but i m not able get the command for the get from github. Can you help me to get the same? Thanks

Comment: @Neha `git-tfs` which is a two-way bridge between TFS (Team Foundation Server) and git. However if you are using TFS2013 and later, you could use Git as the source control option. You could directly  use normal git command such as `git pull`, `git push`. For the command to the get from github, just use the normal git command such as: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I used the same yesterday and it worked. but thanks for your reply